# sparse sparse product A^T*A optim in Eigen lib

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication, eigen3

In the case of multiple of same matrix matA, like

```
matA.transpose()*matA,
```

You don't have to compute all result product, because the result matrix is symmetric(so only if the m>n), in my specific case is always symmetric! square.

So its enough the compute only for. ex. lower triangular part and rest only copy..... because the results of the multiple 2nd and 3rd row, resp.col, is the same like 3rd and 2nd.....And etc....

So my question is , exist way how to tell Eigen, to compute only lower part. and  optionally save to only lower trinaguler part the product?

```
    DATA = SparseMatrix<double>((SparseMatrix<double>(matA.transpose()) * matA).pruned()).toDense();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__QuickRefPage.html#title14), you can evaluate the lower triangle of a matrix with:

```
m1.triangularView<Eigen::Lower>() = m2 + m3;
```

or in your case:

```
m1.triangularView<Eigen::Lower>() = matA.transpose()*matA;
```

(where it says "Writing to a specific triangular part: (only the referenced triangular part is evaluated)"). Otherwise, in the line you've written
Eigen will calculate the entire sparse matrix `matA.transpose()*matA`.

Regarding saving the resulting `m1` matrix, it is the same as saving whatever type of matrix it is (`Eigen::MatrixXt` or `Eigen::SparseMatrix<t>`). If `m1` is sparse, then it will be only half the size of a straightforward `matA.transpose()*matA`. If `m1` is dense, then it will be the full square matrix.

Comment: So the when I save only .triangularView<Eigen::Lower>(), it will be automatically coompute half of result product? like O(n^3 /2),

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "save". In the above example, only the lower triangle will be calculated, whatever the complexity.

Comment: it looks like some incorrect values if I store to dense product of this multiplactaion,..all zeros

Comment: is this correct?: DATA.triangularView<Lower>()-= largestEvalue * approx * approx.transpose();

Comment: Again, I have no idea what "correct" is. I don't know what any of those variables are. There is no information as to what they are. For all I know, `largestEvalue` is 0. Questions need context.

Answer (score 4):

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseSelfAdjointView.html

The symmetric rank update is defined as:

```
B = B + alpha * A * A^T
```

where `alpha` is a scalar. In your case, you are doing A^T * A, so you should pass the transposed matrix instead. The resulting matrix will only store the upper or lower portion of the matrix, whichever you prefer. For example:

```
SparseMatrix<double> B;
B.selfadjointView<Lower>().rankUpdate(A.transpose());
```