# Eigen: Fast way to compute (A^T * A) for sparse A

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen, least-squares, eigen3

I want to solve series of least squares problem (gauss-newton solver, basically) for sparse (crs/ccs) matrix `A`. One of the most time consuming operation is `H = A^T * A` product. `A`'s have different numerical values, but same sparsity, so sparsity of `H` is constant during computations. Assume that `A` have more rows than columns.

My main question is: what is the right way to perform this product really fast? I know about matrix-free solvers, but currently i want to explore analytical solutions.

Also i have several small questions

1) Do computing only triangular part optimization ([sparse sparse product A^T*A optim in Eigen lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784501/sparse-sparse-product-ata-optim-in-eigen-lib)) makes any sense in presence of vectorization?

2) How can i tell eigen that sparsity of `H` is constant? So eigen should use already preallocated buffer and should not check result pattern.

3) Which order of `A` and `H` is more beneficial for `H = A^T * A`, row major or column major?

Thank you for your answers, and sorry for my English

Comment: Points 1+2 are existing (non-trivial) feature requests: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=285, https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=385. Point 3 might depend on your actual problem, though generally I'd assume that transposing into a temporary and having everything in the same majorness for the product is the fastest (this is essentially done implicitly by Eigen).

Comment: And vectorization would only make sense, if you have dense sub-blocks or maybe with [AVX2-gather loads](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vgatherdps:vgatherqps) -- neither is currently properly implemented in Eigen (fixed sized sub-blocks may partially work, but only experimentally)

Comment: @chtz thank you very much for answer! So i can start to search solution outside Eigen. Can you recommend any  good implementation of A'A outside Eigen?