# Compilation error when computing _H.triangularView<Eigen::Lower>() = _Jiew.transpose() * _J;

Tags: sparse-matrix, eigen3

I am running the following code using eigen3:

```
_H.resize(_J.cols(), _J.cols());
_H.triangularView<Eigen::Lower>() = _Jiew.transpose() * _J;
```

with `Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> _J`, but I get the following compilation error:

`In file included from /home/enrico/catkin_ws/external/horizon_gui/horizon/cpp/src/sqp_test.cpp:1: /home/enrico/catkin_ws/external/horizon_gui/horizon/cpp/src/sqp.h: In instantiation of ‘const DMDict& horizon::SQPGaussNewton<CASADI_TYPE>::solve(const DM&, const DM&, const DM&, const DM&, const DM&, const DM&) [with CASADI_TYPE = casadi::Matrix<casadi::SXElem>; casadi::DMDict = std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, casadi::Matrix<double> >; casadi::DM = casadi::Matrix<double>]’: /home/enrico/catkin_ws/external/horizon_gui/horizon/cpp/src/sqp_test.cpp:36:49:   required from here /home/enrico/catkin_ws/external/horizon_gui/horizon/cpp/src/sqp.h:233:47: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘const Eigen::TriangularView<const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, 1>’ and ‘const Eigen::Product<Eigen::Transpose<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >, Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, 2>’) 233 |             _H.triangularView<Eigen::Lower>() = _J.transpose() * _J; |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:88, from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:1, from /home/enrico/catkin_ws/external/horizon_gui/horizon/cpp/src/wrapped_function.h:5, from /home/enrico/catkin_ws/external/horizon_gui/horizon/cpp/src/sqp.h:5, from /home/enrico/catkin_ws/external/horizon_gui/horizon/cpp/src/sqp_test.cpp:1: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/TriangularMatrix.h:220:5: note: candidate: ‘Eigen::TriangularView<MatrixType, Mode>& Eigen::TriangularView<MatrixType, Mode>::operator=(const Eigen::TriangularView<MatrixType, Mode>&) [with _MatrixType = const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>; unsigned int _Mode = 1]’ 220 |     EIGEN_INHERIT_ASSIGNMENT_OPERATORS(TriangularView) |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/TriangularMatrix.h:220:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const Eigen::Product<Eigen::Transpose<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >, Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, 2>’ to ‘const Eigen::TriangularView<const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, 1>&’ 220 |     EIGEN_INHERIT_ASSIGNMENT_OPERATORS(TriangularView) |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/SparseCore:60, from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Sparse:26, from /home/enrico/catkin_ws/external/horizon_gui/horizon/cpp/src/wrapped_function.h:6, from /home/enrico/catkin_ws/external/horizon_gui/horizon/cpp/src/sqp.h:5, from /home/enrico/catkin_ws/external/horizon_gui/horizon/cpp/src/sqp_test.cpp:1: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseTriangularView.h:25:56: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Eigen::TriangularViewImpl<const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, 1, Eigen::Sparse>& Eigen::TriangularViewImpl<const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, 1, Eigen::Sparse>::operator=(Eigen::TriangularViewImpl<const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, 1, Eigen::Sparse>&&)’ 25 | template<typename MatrixType, unsigned int Mode> class TriangularViewImpl<MatrixType,Mode,Sparse> |                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseTriangularView.h:25:56: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const Eigen::Product<Eigen::Transpose<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >, Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, 2>’ to ‘Eigen::TriangularViewImpl<const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, 1, Eigen::Sparse>&&’ /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseTriangularView.h:25:56: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Eigen::TriangularViewImpl<const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, 1, Eigen::Sparse>& Eigen::TriangularViewImpl<const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, 1, Eigen::Sparse>::operator=(const Eigen::TriangularViewImpl<const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, 1, Eigen::Sparse>&)’ /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseTriangularView.h:25:56: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const Eigen::Product<Eigen::Transpose<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >, Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, 2>’ to ‘const Eigen::TriangularViewImpl<const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, 1, Eigen::Sparse>&’ make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/sqp_test.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/sqp_test.dir/src/sqp_test.cpp.o] Error 1 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:106: CMakeFiles/sqp_test.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2`

The thing that is not clear to me is: I copied this part of code from another source where I was using dense `Eigen::MatrixXd` and it compiles without problems.
Am I doing something wrong with sparse matrices and/or there is another way to compute only a triangular part of the product `J.transpose()*J`?

Thank you very much!

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```cpp
    #include <Eigen/Dense>
    #include <Eigen/Sparse>

    int main(){
 
    // This compile
    Eigen::MatrixXd A, B;
    A.resize(8,8);
    A.setRandom(8,8);
    B.resize(8, 8);
    B.triangularView<Eigen::Upper>() = A.transpose()*A;

    //This does not compile
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> J, H;
    J.resize(8, 8);
    J.setIdentity();
    H.resize(8, 8);
    H.triangularView<Eigen::Upper>() = J.transpose()*J;

    }
```

I added as well some "extra" code such as `setRandom()` and `setIdentity()` which is not really necessary for the issue.

I am using Eigen 3.3.7 on Ubuntu 20.04.

I solved using [`_H.selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>().rankUpdate(_J.transpose())`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784501/sparse-sparse-product-ata-optim-in-eigen-lib) .

Comment: This part of the error message `operand types are ‘const Eigen::TriangularView<const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, 1>’` appears to indicate that `_H` is const (the `resize()` call should not work either in that case, but you probably did only show part of the error message). Generally, please post a [mre]!

Comment: Thank you @chtz, actually it is the full error stack. As you suggested I added a minimal reproducible example. I have also added the version of Eigen I am using.

Comment: It appears you solved the problem yourself. You can either delete the question, or if you believe this information will be useful to others in the future, post your solution below as an answer.