# Eigen Mulitiplication of a Sparse matrix with its transpose very slow

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen, matrix-multiplication

I am using the Eigen library in C++ to multiply transpose of a sparse matrix with itself. The size of the matrix is around 1080 times 1040, the matrix is very sparse, each row only contains about 2 nonzero elements. But the code is very slow, it takes around 40 seconds to do the multiplication (the last line of code).

Update: the last line is very slow.

A snippet of my code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/QR>
#include<Eigen/SparseQR>
#include <Eigen/SparseCholesky>
#include <chrono>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>

Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> eigenMat(mat.rows(),mat.cols());

        eigenMat.resize(mat.rows(), mat.cols());
        const double tolerance = 1e-8;

        for (std::size_t c = 0; c < mat.cols(); c++)
        {
            for (std::size_t r = 0; r < mat.rows(); r++)
            {
               // eigenMat.coeffRef(r, c) = mat(r, c);
                 double value = mat(r, c);
                if (std::abs(value) < tolerance)
                {
                    eigenMat.coeffRef(r, c) = value;
                }
            }
        }

Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> eigenMatTranspose = eigenMat.transpose();

Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> modifiedLhs(mat.cols(), mat.cols()); 
 
modifiedLhs = (eigenMatTranspose* eigenMat);
```

I think this is not normal, it should only take less than 0.01 seconds to do this kind of multiplication. Any idea or suggestions about how to fix it?
Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Did you compile your code with compiler optimizations enabled?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Compiler optimizations aren't going to make that much difference.

Comment: Which of the lines is slow? What is the definition for `mat`? Looking at the `for` loops, you seem to be un-Sparse-ifying the array - why not just `Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> eigenMat(mat);` or similar?

Comment: @KenY-N It is the last line that is slow.
modifiedLhs = (eigenMatTranspose* eigenMat);

Comment: You could check the sparseness of `eigenMat`. I am not convinced by the line `eigenMat.coeffRef(r, c) = mat(r, c);`. What happens if `mat(r, c);` is equal to zero ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which would clear up the confusion about your definition of `mat`. As it stands, your initialization of `eigenMat` looks entirely silly and most likely causes the issues with the following matrix multiplication

Comment: @Damien I just updated the code, so when the value of mat(r,c) is less than a tolerance, then it will not be assigned to the sparse matrix

Comment: @Pew Good. And then, what is the consequence on the efficiency ?

Comment: @Damien Not too much difference, I checked the matrix eigenMat, it is indeed very sparse

Comment: @Damien Wait a second, I think I made a silly mistake, it should be std::abs(value) > tolerance instead of <! lol

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eigen sparse matrix A.transpose()\*A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76514151/eigen-sparse-matrix-a-transposea)

Comment: To check the sparseness, you can use `eigenMat.nonZeros();` function.

Comment: @Damien Thank you very much! The problem is solved, it is because I assign zeroes to the sparse matrix. Instead if an element is zero or close to zero, I should do nothing!

Comment: Your whole assignment loop looks like you should replace it with [`eigenMat = mat.sparseView()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__SparseCore__Module.html#ga320dd291cbf4339c6118c41521b75350) but without seeing the relevant code (because, again, this is not a minimum reproducible example), this is only a guess

Comment: @Homers，yes, the problem is in the assignment loop, I shouldn't have assigned zero to the sparse matrix which makes it non-sparse

Comment: @Homer512 I tried with these  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76514151/eigen-sparse-matrix-a-transposea, but I experienced a bug